# apache httpd disable directory browser

Tags: apache, .htaccess, security, web, directory-browsing

I have configured apache by add Options -Indexes to disable directory browser but how can I access resources from website: in my html file (website from host1) has image take from one another server apache (host2), so if I set Options -Indexes in apache (host2) to prevent directory browser then image in my html can't access,too. How to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why would a web page, or anything else other than a human, need to access a directory listing? `Options -Indexes` only stops a directory listing from being generated, it does not prevent access to any of the resources.